# php not parsing file; Just returns code

Tags: php, apache, oop, parsing

I have got a problem where my class apparently is not being parsed correctly and the all files appear to be in place correctly.

Here is my hierarchy:

```
|
|_'_includes'
|__classes
|___class.login.php
|___class.fmdb.php
|__'fm_api'
|___FileMaker.php
|
|_'public_html'
|__login.php
```

(I hope that makes sense - the ones encapsulated in quotes are the folders)

My problem is that apparently my code is not getting parsed correctly and the browser is just showing the class code.

Here are my two classes where it reaches:

class.login.php:

```
<?php

require_once ('config/config.constants.php');
require_once ('classes/class.fmdb.php');
/**
 * Performs all the Login actions
 *
 * @author RichardC
 */
class Login {

    protected $fm;
    protected $fmdb;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->fm = new FileMaker(constant('FMDB_NAME'), constant('FMDB_IP'), constant('FMDB_USERNAME'), constant('FMDB_PASSWORD'));
        $this->fmdb = new FMDB();
    }
}
```

class.fmdb.php:

```
<?php

require_once ('fm_api/FileMaker.php');
/**
 * Database interface for the Scheduler
 *
 * @author RichardC
 */
class FMDB {

    /**
     * Setting the class-wide variables
     */
    protected $fm;
    protected $layout = '';
    protected $records = array();

    public $lastObj = null;


    /**
     * The constructor of the class
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $this->fm = new FileMaker(FMDB_NAME, FMDB_IP, FMDB_USERNAME, FMDB_PASSWORD);
    }

    /**
     * Returns an Error if there is one, for example: error 401 (record missing)
     * 
     * @author  RichardC 
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 2.0
     * 
     * @param obj    $request_object
     * 
     * @return int (error Code || 0 on no error)
     */
    public static function isError($request_object) {
        //The reason it returns 0 instead of false is due to the getCode() method, which will return the original error code so you can check if isError( $res ) > 0
        return (FileMaker::isError($request_object) ? $request_object->getCode() : 0);
    }

    /**
     * Selects data from a FileMaker Database
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param string    $layout
     * @param array     $arrSearchCriteria
     * @param bool      $recordId (true to get the Record ID or false to ignore)
     * 
     * @example $objScheduler->select('someLayout', array( 'FieldName'  =>  'Value' ), true);
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function select($layout, $arrSearchCriteria) {

        $arrOut = array();

        if ((!is_array($arrSearchCriteria))) {
            return false;
        }

        $findReq = $this->fm->newFindCommand($layout);

        foreach ($arrSearchCriteria as $field => $value) {
            $findReq->addFindCriterion($field, $value);
        }

        $results = $findReq->execute();

        //Checks for an error
        if ($this->isError($results) === 0) {
            $records = $results->getRecords();

            //Set the last layout used
            $this->layout = $layout;
            $this->lastObj = $records;

            foreach ($records as $record) {

                $arrOut[] = $record;

                foreach ($record->getFields() as $field) {
                    $this->records[] = $field;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $arrOut['errorCode'] = $this->isError($results);
        }

        return $arrOut;
    }

    /**
     * Secures a string using mysql_real_escape_string and htmlentities
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param string $string
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function fm_escape_string($string) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($string));
    }

    /**
     * Get the records returned by the Select in an array
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @return  array
     */
    public function getRecords() {
        return $this->records;
    }

    /**
     * Set fields by in the Layout with the given fields and values
     *
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.2
     * 
     * @param array     $arrFields 
     * 
     * @note    If you want to specify a layout, please use the update function.
     * 
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function setFields($arrFields) {

        $blOut = false;

        if ((!is_array($arrFields))) {
            return false;
        }

        $layout = (empty($layout) ? ($this->layout) : ($layout));
        $records = $this->lastObj;

        // The record object is already initialised
        if (isset($records) && !empty($records)) {

            foreach ($records as $record) {
                foreach ($arrFields as $fieldName => $value) {

                    $setFields[] = $record->setField($fieldName, $value);
                }
            }

            $commit = $record->commit();

            if ($this->isError($commit) === 0) {
                $blOut = true;
            } else {
                return $this->isError($commit);
            }
        }

        //Speed things up
        unset($record, $commit, $fieldName, $value);

        return $blOut;
    }


    /**
     * Update the fields on a layout with specified data
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param   string  $layout
     * @param   array   $arrFields
     * @param   int     $iRecordID
     * 
     * @example $objFM->update('exampleLayout', array('Field1' => 'This is the data which Field1 will be updated with'), 1);
     * 
     * @return  boolean
     */
    public function updateRecordByID($layout, $arrFields, $iRecordID) {
        $blOut = false;

        if (($layout == '') || (!is_array($arrFields)) || (!is_number($iRecordID))) {
            return false;
        }

        $findReq = $this->fm->newFindCommand($layout);

        //Loops through setting the where clause
        foreach ($where as $field => $value) {
            $findReq->addFindCriterion($field, '==' . $value);
        }

        $result = $findReq->execute();

        //Checks for errors
        if ($this->isError($result) === 0) {
            $result = $this->fm->getRecordById($layout, $iRecordID);

            //Loops through each result from the 'Select'
            foreach ($records as $record) {
                //Loops through all given fields and values, setting the fields to be said values
                foreach ($arrRecords as $f => $v) {
                    $record->setField($f, $v);
                }
                $commit = $record->commit();
            }
            //Checking for errors
            if ($this->isError($commit) === 0) {
                $blOut = true;
            } else {
                return $this->isError($commit);
            }
        } else {
            return $this->isError($result);
        }

        // Speed things up
        unset($result, $commit, $record, $findReq);

        return $blOut;
    }

    /**
     * Inserts a record into the Table/Layout with the given data from $arrFields
     *
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param string $layout
     * @param array  $arrFields
     * 
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function insert($layout, $arrFields) {

        $blOut = false;

        if (($layout == '') || (!is_array($arrFields))) {
            return false;
        }

        $addCmd = $this->fm->newAddCommand($layout, $arrFields);
        $result = $addCmd->commit();

        if ($this->isError($result) === 0) {
            $blOut = true;
        } else {
            return $this->isError($result);
        }

        //Speed things up
        unset($addCmd, $result);

        return $blOut;
    }

    /**
     * List Layout Names from Database
     *
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_layout_names() {
        return $this->fm->listLayouts();
    }

    /**
     * Alias of the select function
     *
     * @author RichardC
     * @since  1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param string $layout
     * @param array  $arrSearchCriteria
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function find($layout, $arrSearchCriteria) {
        return $this->select($layout, $arrSearchCriteria);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of rows in a given query
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     * 
     * @param array $arrResult
     * 
     * @return int 
     */
    public function fm_num_rows($arrResult) {
        return (!is_array($arrResult) ? 0 : count($arrResult));
    }


    /**
     * Runs a script on the server from the web
     * 
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @version 1.0
     *
     * @param string $layout
     * @param string $scriptName 
     * @param array  $params (Optional depending on the script params that you wish to execute)
     * 
     * return boolean
     */
    public function runScript($layout, $scriptName, $params = array()) {
        $blOut = false;

        if ((empty($layout)) || (empty($scriptName))) {
            return $blOut;
        }

        if ($this->fm->newPerformScriptCommand($layout, $scriptName, $params)) {
            $blOut = true;
        }

        return $blOut;
    }

    /**
     * Rec-ID (FileMaker Record ID hidden field)
     * 
     * LayoutName, Field Value, FieldName
     */
    public function getLastID() {

    }

    public function delete($layout, $iRecordID) {
        // Example from $this->update :: $result = $this->fm->getRecordById($layout, $iRecordID);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the record ID from the current record
     *
     * @author  RichardC
     * @since   1.0
     * 
     * @return int 
     */

    public function getRecordId() {
        return $this->lastObj->getRecordId();
    }
}

?>
```

And this is what gets returned when I call the functions:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Tn7fh.png]

For reasons that some of this is confidential due to its nature I cannot show you all of the code, but any suggestions on why this may be happening would be a great help!

Thanks!

**[Edit]**

Sorry, the code I show are only snippets of each class. I cannot post the full class code as it is a work-related project.

Comment: "is just showing the class code" which class? The text verbatim from FileMaker.php?

Comment: Are you missing a `<?php` in whatever file you're accessing through your browser?

Comment: @Viruzzo: it is showing the text from class.fmdb.php

Comment: @jprofitt: It was only a snippet of the code, sorry I did not make that clear

Comment: Has this code always done this or did it start happening after you moved to a different machine?

Comment: @jray: it has just started doing this. And I am not sure what I did to cause it.

Comment: Try replacing it with a simple "Hello World"-kind of PHP file. Also, require it with the file name only (using "classes" there is wrong in any case).

Comment: I will try it and let you know, but why is using classes wrong as a folder structure?

Comment: I tried it and nothing got outputted, it was a bit more complicated than just changing it to be a hello world file as it calls methods within that class and obviously that broke as well.

Comment: I have had this error when I was using short tags <? ?>, and the short_tags was not enabled in the PHP config. That seems to be proper here, but might be worth a try to enable to same in the PHP Config, PHPINFO().

Answer (score -4, accepted):

you have no closing php tag?  ?>, although it's optional it might be necessary since your including other files.

Comment: Huh? As far as I know, a closing PHP tag is never necessary (also, bad style).

Comment: A closing PHP tag should ALWAYS be there. It is very bad practice if it is not there. It can infact cause some errors.

Comment: your correct they are not always necessary.  They are if your using escaped HTML code in your php file. but if your using straight php then it is fine not to the have an ending close tag.  But your also including files so it's possibly having no closing tag may be causing a problem.

Comment: I have got closing tags in there, its just you can't see the whole class as I cannot post it publically. Sorry.

Comment: From the PHP manual for include(): _"When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be executed as PHP code **must** be enclosed within valid PHP start and end tags."_

Comment: Another option is try removing all your comments temporarily.  They might be causing an issue.

Comment: I gave that ago @Robert but to no avail, it didn't make any difference :/

Comment: Another thing could be a missing opening tag in one of the includes or main file.  where is the code that is being written out, is it not included in your snippets?

Comment: @Robert I just stripped it all out and the issue was the comments, I'm nto sure why but thanks again! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Is the file being interpreted as PHP by your webserver? Not all servers are setup by defalut to do this and you occationally need to do it yourself via .htaccess (assuming you are using apache)

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
```

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work, my webserver is setup to interporate PHP files. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!

Comment: have you verified the version of php?  I wouldn't think it would matter but it's possible.