# PHP on amazon AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I need to do a small project with php. As I need a publicly accessible website and due to the lack of space on my network, I decided to setup an amazon linux web server to try it out. I installed the LAMP package on it. I am able to access the web server using the public address with no problem. The web directory is located at /var/www, but I am not sure where or how to enable PHP. Can someone shed some light on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest/trivial way would be to create an `index.php` file under `/var/www`

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And access it

```
111.222.333.444/index.php
```

And see the output - the info page will be displayed if `php` is up and running.

---

**Update**

Also make sure your [webserver is interpreting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230331/php-not-parsing-file-just-returns-code) the `.php` files

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php5 .phtml
```

Comment: I already tried that. It doesn't seem to work for some reason. Only static html files work.

Comment: Could you `ssh` to your server and run `/etc/init.d/apache2 status`? What is the output?

Comment: it does not exist. actually i did "locate apache2", but it does not exist. I performed the installation according to this:   http://www.getanahita.com/pages/128908-how-to-install-apache-or-lamp-stack-on-an-ec2-linux-instance

Comment: Ok, go for `sudo service apahce2 status`

Comment: apache2: unrecognized service. same when i try apache (without 2). When i try sudo service httpd status, i get httpd (pid 2121) is running.